# Stop infinite page load in selenium webdriver - python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am loading a page using selenium web driver.But the page is loading infinitely.
I tried to catch the exception and simulate the esc key action but that didn't helped.Due to some constraints I can use only Firefox[I have seen the chrome add on solution]. Once I hit the page I am not getting the control back.

I set my Firefox profile as

```
    firefoxProfile = FirefoxProfile()
    firefoxProfile.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
    firefoxProfile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
    firefoxProfile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so','false')
    firefoxProfile.set_preference("http.response.timeout", 10)
    firefoxProfile.set_preference("dom.max_script_run_time", 10)
```

Script to stop loading :

```
 try:
       driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
       driver.get('http://www.example.com'     
 except Exception
        print 'time out'
        driver.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL +'Escape')
```

Comment: Can you share the actual URL you are using?

Comment: This is my company project so I cant share the URL in public.That will create unnecessary problems.

Comment: Okay, I understand, what you would not set the profile preferences at all? Is it still loading forever? Also, have you tried to wait 30+ seconds?

Comment: It is loading correctly if i didn't set any Firefox profile but the issue is the page is having more than 100 big size images.This makes the loading  process really slow .So I though to disable images .

Comment: Got it, thanks. What selenium and firefox versions are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help.I am using selenium 2.45 with Firefox 38.1

Comment: Ok, for starters, upgrade selenium to 2.46. This alone may solve it.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. However it didn't helped to stop the page load. However Instead trying to stop the page load if i try to apply the x-path to extract content in exception block i can get the content which i want,with even the page is still loading .So I am applying the x-paths to extract the content and close that window.

Answer (score 10):

I see a couple of typos in your try/except block, so let's correct those really quickly...

```
try:
      driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
      driver.get('http://www.example.com')
except Exception:
      print 'time out'
      driver.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL +'Escape')
```

I have been working with Selenium and Python for a while now (also using Firefox webdriver). Also, I'm assuming you're using Python, just from the syntax of your code.

Anyways, your Firefox profile should help resolve the issue, but it doesn't look like you're actually applying it to the *driver* instance.

Try something along these lines:

```
from selenium import webdriver # import webdriver to create FirefoxProfile

firefoxProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefoxProfile.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
firefoxProfile.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)
firefoxProfile.set_preference('dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.libflashplayer.so','false')
firefoxProfile.set_preference("http.response.timeout", 10)
firefoxProfile.set_preference("dom.max_script_run_time", 10)

# now create browser instance and APPLY the FirefoxProfile
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefoxProfile)
```

This works for me, using Python 2.7 and Selenium 2.46.

Source (Selenium docs): http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#how-to-auto-save-files-using-custom-firefox-profile (scroll down a tiny bit til you see code block under "Here is an example:")

Let me know how it goes, and good luck!

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion .The issue was already fixed by applying xpath on exception block as I mentioned earlier in my comment

Comment: Sure. I still suggest adding that one line of code `driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefoxProfile)` so that your firefoxProfile code is actually used because right now, it is not